# is there any way to user hot restart/hot reload functionality for native java code along with flutter dart code?

Tags: flutter, hot-reload, flutter-hotreload

if i make changes in native flutter code, while my flutter dart code is running can I view changes using hot/hot restart?

For now, if open andrdoid folder into android studio and make changes, and run app/activity it gets disconnected with dart on flutter project level.

[Read here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/hot-reload), that hot reload/hot restart will only work on Dart VM and native Java does not comes under Dart VM, so bye bye hot restart for native.

Appreciate any help, facing slow developer experience.